# Qt Designer layouts don't respect pre-defined geometry

Tags: python, layout, pyqt, qt-designer

I'm creating a new `QWidget` in Qt Designer, with a `frame` which contains a `QLabel` and a `QTextEdit`. I can set the geometry of all these elements, and set them to be `fixed` so that their height/width never change:

[image]

In this example, my `QLabel` and `QLineEdit` are in the top right-hand corner of their parent frame.  If I now set a layout to the frame (which I need to do to ensure elements remain in their correct place when resizing windows, or if the frame is the main widget of a `QScrollArea`), then the elements are moved, even within the reference of the frame:

[image]

In this instance, a Form Layout was applied to the frame; we can see the (X,Y) coords of the `QLabel` have changed from (0,0) to (10,10).  This happens whether I wrap the two elements in a vertical frame beforehand or not.

Given I'm trying to create a very precise layout by manually setting the element coords, to have them move a seemingly random amount when applying a layout is hugely frustrating.  What should I be doing?!  I assume I've misunderstood something, but I don't know what!

Comment: I think your problems are caused by the use of form-layout, as well as issues with the default margins and spacing. Anyway, I have updated my answer with a solution that works for your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Layouts have a default margin and spacing, the precise values of which are provided by the current widget style.

You can override the defaults by clicking on the parent widget of the layout, and scrolling down to the bottom of the Property Editor, where you'll see a Layout section with the relevant values (`-1` means "use the default").

**EDIT**:

One thing I didn't make clear was that the layout margins and spacing will go back to their defaults every time you break and reset the layout! This can be very annoying at times, but does make sense, because a new layout is created every time you do this.

Anyway, I think the real source of the problem is actually that you are using a Form Layout, which can be much less flexible than the other layouts. What I think you should do is put the label and line-edit in an Horizontal Layout with a Horizontal Spacer at the end. Then put a Vertical Spacer below the Horizontal Layout, and add a Vertical Layout to the Frame. This arrangement will keep the label and line-edit in the top-left corner of the Frame. With that in place, you can finally set the Vertical Layout margins to zero to get the desired result.

Here is a .ui file you can test to see how it all goes together:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>316</width>
    <height>150</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
   <item row="0" column="0">
    <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
     <property name="frameShape">
      <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
     </property>
     <property name="frameShadow">
      <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
     </property>
     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
      <property name="spacing">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <property name="margin">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <item>
       <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
        <property name="spacing">
         <number>0</number>
        </property>
        <item>
         <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
          <property name="sizePolicy">
           <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
            <horstretch>0</horstretch>
            <verstretch>0</verstretch>
           </sizepolicy>
          </property>
          <property name="minimumSize">
           <size>
            <width>75</width>
            <height>0</height>
           </size>
          </property>
          <property name="text">
           <string>TextLabel</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item>
         <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit">
          <property name="sizePolicy">
           <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
            <horstretch>0</horstretch>
            <verstretch>0</verstretch>
           </sizepolicy>
          </property>
          <property name="minimumSize">
           <size>
            <width>100</width>
            <height>0</height>
           </size>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </item>
        <item>
         <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
          <property name="orientation">
           <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
          </property>
          <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
           <size>
            <width>40</width>
            <height>20</height>
           </size>
          </property>
         </spacer>
        </item>
       </layout>
      </item>
      <item>
       <spacer name="verticalSpacer">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
         <size>
          <width>20</width>
          <height>106</height>
         </size>
        </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Although this didn't totally answer my question, it did inspire me to rethink my layout strategy!

Comment: A bit out-of-topic but, like ChrisW, "inspiring". I was having a weird problem where a QFormLayout was "compacting" all the widgets, even when the default spacing (6) was displayed in the designer. I manually change it after reading this I changed it to -1 and it now is showing widgets correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The key elements that influence positioning and size that you need to pay attention to are:

1. the layout of your base form
2. layouts within your form
3. widget sizepolicy and widget min and max size values

All of the elements work in conjunction in a cascading fashion.  It usually takes a lot a trials and CTRL+R to evaluate the appearance and resize nature of the form, but it is usually these 3 things.

Answer (score 0):

The point of layouts is that they control the size and position of the elements in them.  This is how they work.  If they weren't in control of the widget geometry, what would they do when resized?

Instead of trying to rigidly control the size and position of everything, use layouts to convey design intent: These two controls belong together, these identical items should be in a column, and so on.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps I've been doing the whole thing wrong? I laid out the elements (in my real life instance, I'm using `QScrollArea`s and a `QTabWidget`), and for these elements to be displayed correctly, they then have to have a layout applied. A `QWidget` has to have a Grid Layout applied (afaik?) to ensure that elements stay in the correct place (relatively) when the widget is resized. I'm only setting geometry with (x,y) coords, and min/max sizes, to have a very precise layout (with columns and rows)

Comment: @ChrisW: x and y coords are entirely under control of the layout.  Anything you set will be overridden/ignored.  Min/max sizes will be respected (but if you must have a fixed size, I recommend setting only the minimum size and using a sizePolicy of "Fixed").

Comment: Hmm, this seems to contradict @ekhumoro's answer, since he implies the layout margins can be modified so that the x and y coords are respected

Comment: @ChrisW: I don't think ekhumoro is saying that modifying the margins will cause x and y to be respected, he's saying that the margins are a way to control the positioning behavior of the layout.

Comment: So *how* do you create precise layouts if Qt Designer changes the x & y coords every time I apply a layout?!

Comment: @ChrisW: When you make a "precise" layout, are the absolute x & y coords what you really care about, or are they a means to an end? (Hint: I hope it's the latter.)  You should be more concerned about consistent margins/spacing, alignment between widgets, and proximity of related widgets.  All of these things are easily accomplished with layouts.  Layouts are just a _different_ (and usually better) means to the same end.

Comment: @ChrisW: Maybe a more direct answer to that last question is "use margins, spacing, and other properties."  The sizePolicy and minimumSize properties are often useful.  Also, spacer elements (found in near the top of the "Widget Box" panel are important.

Comment: Yes - I've spent today cursing spacer elements... I'm vaguely more quantitative than qualitative - I'd much rather put a value to things than just seemingly place things at random on a screen and hope it magically appears where I want it to (which is, in my eyes, what designers seem to do); maybe I need to drastically change mindset

Comment: @ChrisW: Layouts actually follow a fairly simple set of rules, they just aren't immediately apparent - keep trying different things, you'll get it figured out.  And get ready to give up some control! :-P  (Don't worry, it's worth it, and you're not giving up as much as you think.)

Comment: @ChrisW. I endorse everything Steve has said in these comments. Setting exact sizes and positions is something to be used only very rarely as a last resort. Qt's layout management isn't perfect, but if you work _with it_, it will give very good results 95% of the time. You do need to give up some control to get the best out of it, but you will get most of that control back again by developing a good understanding of how the system works. This will come with practice.